# Choose Lucene or Solr

Tags: solr, lucene.net

We need to integrate a search engine in our plataform Catalog management software in Share point. The information is stored in multiple databases and a storage of files ( doc , ppt , pdf .....). Our dev platform is Asp.Net and we have done some pre-liminary work on Lucene, found it to be good. However, we just came to know of Solr.
We need to continue using lucene, but we need to defend her the solr.
Please any help is accepted.
And sorry for my english.

Comment: Go for Solr or Elasticsearch. They will leverage a lot of work from your.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is a full-text search library used to provide search functionalities to an application. It can't be used as an application by itself. Solr is a complete search engine built around Lucene providing its search functionalities and others. Solr is a web application that can be used by itself without any development around it.
If you need a search engine to be called by your application I recommend you to use Solr.